# One template for multiple similar HierarchicalDataTemplate-s?

Tags: wpf, treeview, controltemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a TreeView component, and it can contain several types of nodes. Its all working well except I have multiple hierarchical data templates which differ just in the glyph image they display, DataType and ItemsSource but everything else is exactly the same.

I was wondering, is it possible to create just one ControlTemplate for all hierarchical data template and just modify the icon image by using the tag property?

So for example I have basic TreeNode class and nodes like, PersonNode, PropertyNode, StreetNode which inherit from TreeNode. TreeNode displays a folder icon, PersonNode displays a user icon, PropertyNode displays house icon and StreeNode displays street icon.
So, actually they all have same content structure except, the icon, DataType and ItemsSource are changing.

How can I simplify my hierarchical data templates?

Sample code:

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate
    DataType="{x:Type MyTreeFolder:TreeNode}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSpecialNode}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>

        <glyphs:GlyphAwesome 
            FontSize="12"
            Glyph="folder"
            Margin="0, 0, 4, 0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                
    </StackPanel>
    
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you show one of your data templates? Where are the images defined, in XAML, in your node types?

Comment: @thatguy I added sample template, but will I be able to achieve this with ordinary UserControl?

Comment: @thatguy so just delete the question, no plausible solution to the problem?

Comment: There are solutions to this issue. From where do you get `GlyphAwesome`?

Comment: @thatguy that is the biggest problem, the glyph? Its a library we use to draw vector icons instead of using bitmap images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a value converter that checks the type of the tree node and returns the glyph text. The type to glyph text mapping could be stored in a dictionary.

```
public class ObjectTypeToGlyphConverter : IValueConverter
{
   private static readonly IDictionary<Type, string> TypeToGlyphMapping = new Dictionary<Type, string>
   {
      [typeof(TreeNode)] = "folder",
      [typeof(PersonNode)] = "person",
      [typeof(PropertyNode)] = "property"
   };

   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      var type = value?.GetType();
      return type != null && TypeToGlyphMapping.TryGetValue(type, out var glyph) ? glyph : null;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

You would need to create an instance of this converter in a resource dictionary in scope, e.g.:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeNodes}">
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <local:ObjectTypeToGlyphConverter x:Key="ObjectTypeToGlyphConverter"/>
   </TreeView.Resources>
   <!-- ...tree view definitions. -->
</TreeView>
```

Then you could use it in your hierarchical data template's `GlyphAwesome` like this.

```
<glyphs:GlyphAwesome FontSize="12"
                     Glyph="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ObjectTypeToGlyphConverter}}"
                     Margin="0, 0, 4, 0"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

In this case you would only need one data template for the type `TreeNode`, given that as you say all node types are essentially the same and there is no special handling for them except for the icon.